# Is it possible to override the destructor of MyClass* (not MyClass)?

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor

for example, I have a class with different containers to hold MyClass object created by new operator:

```
class A{
    MyClass* m;
    vector<MyClass*> vm;
    vector<vector<MyClass> > vvm;
    pair<int,MyClass*> pim;
};
```

I want to delete all MyClass object in A when A is destroyed, is it possible to override the destructor of MyClass* like:

```
~MyClass*(){
    delete *this;
}
```

to replace custom destructor:

```
~A(){
    delete m;
    for(MyClass* m : this->vm){
        delete m;
    }
    for(vector<MyClass*> vm : this->vvm){
        for(MyClass* m : this->vm){
            delete m;
        }
    }
    delete pim.second;
}
```

so that I am no need to add new code when a type of container is added to hold the reference of MyClass?

Comment: If you use `std::share_ptr<MyClass>`, you can just have `A::~A(){}`.

Comment: you beat me to it R Sahu. Though isn't it `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>`?

Comment: @CommanderBubble, yes it is `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the liberty of using `std::shared_ptr<MyClass>` instead of raw pointers, you can simplify the destructor of `A`.

```
class A {

   public:
      ~A() {} // That's all you need. You can even omit it.

   private:
      std::shared_ptr<MyClass> m;
      vector<std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> vm;
      vector<vector<MyClass> > vvm;
      pair<int,std::shared_ptr<MyClass>> pim;

};
```

Comment: Note that providing an explicit destructor suppresses generation of implicit move-constructor and move-assignment operator , so if you do want those functions then you are actually better off omitting the destructor

Answer (score 0):

An instance of MyClass is created in outside, and you wants that the instance of MyClass is deleted when instance of A is deleted?

If lifecycle of instance of MyClass is dependent to A, then just

class A {

private:

    MyClass m;

}

or If not, then delete instance of MyClass outside.